# Why do we say 'Salt to taste'?

Tags: phrase-usage

Why do we say '*salt to taste*' and don't say '*salt according to taste*' or '*salt for taste*'?

Comment: Because people like to shorten things when they can.

Comment: @Mynamite  but doesn't it sound awkward?

Comment: @Pratyaksh: It's no more "awkward" than a [*work-to-rule*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/work-to-rule), which is a lot less trouble than the union representative calling on the men to support a *work according to [the] rule [book]*.

Comment: Well...... only if you're not accustomed to it, as is clearly your case. But it sounds perfectly normal to me. See Yohann's answer - this is what people understand by the phrase.

Comment: @Mynamite Yeah I know that you're accustomed to it and even I am too accustomed to it but then also I was just relating it to the phrase 'salt according to your taste' and it sounded awkward to my ears with respect to that and hence a question popped out in my mind and I just asked it.

Comment: You can also have something [*adjusted to your preference*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22adjusted+to+your+preference%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (or [*adjusted to **suit** your preference*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22adjusted+to+suit+your+preference%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)), where [*adjusted **according** to your preference*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22adjusted+according+to+your+preference%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) does occur, but is significantly less common.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I guess you can write thesis on it. Am I right? By the way thank you very much.

Comment: @Pratyaksh: I will admit I was scraping the bottom of the barrel to come up with even those two "similar" usages (I can't think of any others in common use). And I spent a few minutes searching online for variants and/or syntactic analysis, so I suspect if anyone *has* written a thesis about it, they never uploaded their work anywhere Google can find it. In short - it's not a very "productive" feature of English, which probably explains why nobody seems to have analysed it in detail.

Comment: **Salt**: v 1. To add, treat, season, or sprinkle with salt. [ [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/salt)] // **to taste** [phrase] 
3 
According to personal liking:
_add salt and pepper to taste_ [ [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/taste)]

Comment: Why is it worded that way?  ..There's no accounting for taste.

Comment: If you have written a hundred times in  a cook book "Salt according to taste" you'll have the idea to say it shorter. "Salt to taste" in a cookbook won't be misunderstood.

Comment: I remember being puzzled as a child to see '[Add] salt to taste' on the label of a peanut butter jar. I thought it meant that you must add salt to give it any flavour, but my mum explained that it meant 'You _may_ add salt if you think it needs some'.

Answer (score 11):

It is a shortcut for

> salt [according] to [your] taste

---

Transversal post : http://www.thekitchn.com/food-science-salting-to-taste-49868

Comment: Actually, what it means is "Salt until it's too salty, then remove some of the salt."

Comment: And because "Add salt to taste" sounds like a rebus.

Comment: I can't find evidence that this deletion has occurred in your linked article. Please quote this. And how do we know that the original wasn't 'Add salt according to your taste'?

Comment: @HotLicks: Piet Hein's [TimingToast](https://www.nbi.dk/~petersen/Quotes/Grooks/grooks.html). *"There's an art of knowing when. Never try to guess. Toast until it smokes and then twenty seconds less."*

Comment: What is a "shortcut" ?

Answer (score 1):

The preposition **to** has long had the meaning "in accordance with". There are attestations from Old English all the way up to the current day.

> It was built to spec.

**taste** refers to individual preference or liking (see, e.g., M-W **taste** noun #4). This meaning goes back to Middle English (as it enters English from medieval French).

**salt** has been a verb since Old English (**sealtan**).

So the imperative construction means "Apply salt in accordance with individual preference".

Answer (score -2):

It's obviously a deleted form.

The only evidence that I can think of that the word 'Add' (salt being the noun) has not been dropped from an original is that the parallel

> 'Dilute to taste'

is also used. However, there is an argument for the contrary:

> 'Spices (to taste)'

is used, and 'Add' **must** have been deleted here.

Again,

> What does "salt and pepper, to taste" mean?

is found at the [Reluctant Gourmet](https://www.reluctantgourmet.com/salt-and-pepper-to-taste/#:%7E:text=They%20both%20mean%20something%20different,want%20the%20dish%20to%20have.), and using 'pepper' as a verb in this domain is very rare.

Comment: But *salt*, *dilute* and even *season* are verbs (or can be). *Spices* isn't, or at least not in this context (you could say "he spices up every meal he cooks by adding..."  but then the verb is *spices up*.

Comment: @ChrisH So Chris now i know that you're trying to say that here salt is treated as a verb similar to season or sprinkle. Right?

Comment: @PratyakshSharma, that's how *I* read it.  It makes the instruction a sentence with a verb rather than a fragment, so I believe that's how many recipe writers see it as well (the ones that generally write in full sentences at least).

Comment: -1 Sorry, Edwin. I normally find myself agreeing with most things you write, but not this time.